# How do I tell if a variable is a file in bash

Tags: bash, terminal

I am not a great `bash` scripter and hence have a few questions. One of which is how (or even whether) `bash` understands that a variable is a "file" or simply a local variable.

```
file=/usr/share/lib
```

Obviously this is a file to be saved, etc and can be used like so:

```
echo "$output" > $file
```

To save the output of `$output` to `$file`.

But where in `bash` does it calculate whether it's a file or not, is it only a file once it's been passed to a 'writing method'?

Comment: I wasn't looking for the test on whether it's a file or not. I was looking for an explanation as to when, why and how it becomes a file.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you treat that variable as a file name, bash will simply do what it's told e.g.

```
echo "Test output" > $file
```

will work regardless of file being set to `/tmp/myfile.txt`, or to `abcd`. In the above you're using bash's [file redirection](http://wiki.bash-hackers.org/syntax/redirection) to write out the standard out to the file you've named.

Consequently if you use the wrong variable in the above pattern, or have the value set incorrectly, bash will simply follow your instructions and you may end up with incorrectly named/located files.

Comment: So piping using `>` and `<` are file operations? Is it possible to use an operation destined to be used on variables, and afterwards onto a file operation?

Comment: > and < aren't *piping*, although there's some relation. > and < are redirection operations. See the document linked above

Comment: Ah, thank you. Is it safe to assume `|` to be linked with piping commands/output?

Comment: The pipe | links input/output of one process to another. > and < work similarly but between files and processes

Comment: I appreciate the guidance. When I first started writing in `bash` I assumed files to be created as soon as they are set to a variable, it's quite a different way of learning but I'm slowly getting there. :)

Answer (score 2):

You need to check this yourself, bash is only aware of the contents of the variable. If you want to check if a file location is held within a variable, you can test for it using the `-f` [test operator](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Bash-Conditional-Expressions.html)

```
if [ -f "$file" ]
then
  echo "$file is a file"
  echo "$output" > "$file"
else
  echo "$file is not a file"
fi
```

Answer (score 0):

Variables are **strings** - nothing more, nothing less.  (I'm ignoring array variables here, WLOG).

Bash (or any shell) expands variables blindly, without considering what you intend to do with them.  It's only in the next stage of command processing that the contents of the string matter.

To use your example:

```
output="foo bar"
file=/usr/share/lib
echo "$output" >"$file"
```

(I've quoted `$file` even though it's not necessary here, simply because I've been bitten too many times by changing the value and breaking everything).

The line

```
echo "$output" >"$file"
```

gets transformed into

```
echo "foo bar" >"/usr/share/lib"
```

and only then does bash consider the `>` and attempt to open `/usr/share/lib` for writing.